# Neater way to handle errors from multiple fread calls

Tags: c, error-handling, fread

I have the following method in C to load a binary file, it seems rather long and tedious having to check the error value from each and every `fread` call, is there a neater way to handle this?

I'm aware that some of the calls could be reduced by reading in a struct in one go, but due to how C can add padding bytes in between struct members, I'd prefer to avoid this.

```
some_type_t *load_something(FILE *file) {
    some_type_t *something = (some_type_t *)malloc(sizeof(some_type_t));
    if (something == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fread(&something->field1, sizeof(something->field1), 1, file) == 0) {
        free(something);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (fread(&something->field2, sizeof(something->field2), 1, file) == 0) {
        free(something);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (fread(&something->field3, sizeof(something->field3), 1, file) == 0) {
        free(something);
        return NULL;
    }

    uint16_t some_var1, some_var2, some_var3;

    some_other_type_t *something_else1 = (some_other_type_t *)malloc(sizeof(some_other_type_t));
    if (fread(&some_var1, sizeof(some_var1), 1, file) == 0) {
        free(something);
        free(something_else1);
        return NULL;
    }

    some_other_type_t *something_else2 = (some_other_type_t *)malloc(sizeof(some_other_type_t));
    if (fread(&some_var2, sizeof(some_var2), 1, file) == 0) {
        free(something);
        free(something_else1);
        free(something_else2);
        return NULL;
    }

    some_other_type_t *something_else3 = (some_other_type_t *)malloc(sizeof(some_other_type_t));
    if (fread(&some_var3, sizeof(some_var3), 1, file) == 0) {
        free(something);
        free(something_else1);
        free(something_else2);
        free(something_else3);
        return NULL;
    }
    // Do something with the vars and allocated something elses.
    // ...

    return something;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not creating a macro:

```
#define READ_FIELD(data) \
    do { if (fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, file) == 0) { \
        free(something); \
        free(something_else1);
        free(something_else2);
        return NULL; \
    } } while(0)
```

then call it like a function call:

```
READ_FIELD(something->field1);
READ_FIELD(something->field2);

READ_FIELD(some_var1);
READ_FIELD(some_var2);
```

the code will be the same but at least it is now generated and not copied/pasted (with possible errors).

The macro has to call `free` on all possible memory blocks, even the ones that aren't allocated yet. The only constraint is to set the unallocated ones to `NULL` so `free` doesn't crash. And to be super safe change as:

```
free(something); something = NULL;
```

(of course if `something` is the copy of an allocated pointer, setting to `NULL` doesn't protect against double free, it has limits)

you can apply this technique to the write side as well, and since M Oehm suggested that, you could make a list of what you want to read/write in a wrapper macro:

```
#define DO_ALL \
    DO_FIELD(something->field1); \
    DO_FIELD(something->field2); \
    DO_FIELD(some_var1); \
    DO_FIELD(some_var2)
```

then define `DO_FIELD` as `READ_FIELD` or `WRITE_FIELD`:

```
#define DO_FIELD READ_FIELD
DO_ALL;
#undef DO_FIELD
```

Comment: Looks appealing, but there's an added complication that the further along I get in the reading, the more things I may need to free. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: you could free everything, even if things aren't already allocated, as long as the pointers are NULL it won't be an issue.

Comment: You could even use a wrapper macro to keep the writing and reading in sync.

Comment: @MOehm yes, defining a macro using read or write first, and calling a generic `DO_SOMETHING_ON_DATA`.

Comment: I like this solution because there's also scope to extend the macro to set or return a different error value for each call as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that could save you to check the success of each and every call, but you can improve on the code structure using `goto` (this is in fact one idiomatic use of `goto` in C, pseudo-code to follow):

```
    if (first_call() < 0) goto error;
    if (second_call() < 0) goto error;

    // [...]
    // when everything succeeded:
    return result;

error:
    // free resources
    // return error-indicator, e.g.
    return 0;
```

If the resources to free accumulate over the course of your function, make sure to first initialize them all to `NULL`/`0` (assuming they are pointers). Then, calling `free()` on them in your `error` part has no effect when they're not allocated yet. If you use own "destructor functions", make sure to design them the same way `free()` is designed -- when passed a NULL value, it should be a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize all `something` pointers to `NULL` and centralise the cleaning up at one place.

```
    ...
    something = something_else1 = something_else2 = something_else3 = NULL;
    ...
    some_other_type_t *something_else3 = (some_other_type_t *)malloc(sizeof(some_other_type_t));
    if (fread(&some_var3, sizeof(some_var3), 1, file) == 0) {
      goto error;
    }
    // Do something with the vars and allocated something elses.
    // ...

    return something;

  error:
    free(something);
    free(something_else1);
    free(something_else2);
    free(something_else3);
    return NULL;
  }
```

Freeing a `NULL` pointer is OK, it does nothing, therefore you don't need to check if the `someting` pointers are `NULL` before calling `free`.

Sidenote: in C you don't cast the return value of  `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to group the `malloc` and `fread` operations and check just once for proper completion:

```
some_type_t *load_something(FILE *file) {
    uint16_t some_var1, some_var2, some_var3;
    some_type_t *something = malloc(sizeof(*something));
    some_other_type_t *something_else1 = malloc(sizeof(*something_else1));
    some_other_type_t *something_else2 = malloc(sizeof(*something_else2));
    some_other_type_t *something_else3 = malloc(sizeof(*something_else3));

    if (!something || !something_else1 || !something_else2 || !something_else3 ||
        !fread(&something->field1, sizeof(something->field1), 1, file) ||
        !fread(&something->field2, sizeof(something->field2), 1, file) ||
        !fread(&something->field3, sizeof(something->field3), 1, file) ||
        !fread(&some_var1, sizeof(some_var1), 1, file) ||
        !fread(&some_var2, sizeof(some_var2), 1, file) ||
        !fread(&some_var3, sizeof(some_var3), 1, file))
    {
        free(something);
        free(something_else1);
        free(something_else2);
        free(something_else3);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Do something with the vars and allocated something elses.
    // ...

    return something;
}
```

Note that passing a null pointer to `free()` is OK.